Error "xf86EnableIO: failed to enable I/O ports 0000-03ff (Function not implemented)" when running startx
Ubuntu version 24.04 LTS.
I am tring to open ubuntu desktop from terminal, and when I run startx as root user I got this
# startx

_XSERVTransmkdir: Mode of /tmp/.X11-unix should be set to 1777
_XSERVTransSocketCreateListener: failed to bind listener
_XSERVTransSocketUNIXCreateListener: ...SocketCreateListener() failed
_XSERVTransMakeAllCOTSServerListeners: failed to create listener for unix

X.Org X Server 1.21.1.11
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Current Operating System: Linux Alec 5.15.153.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2 #1 SMP Fri Mar 29 23:14:13 UTC 2024 x86_64
Kernel command line: initrd=\initrd.img WSL_ROOT_INIT=1 panic=-1 nr_cpus=20 hv_utils.timesync_implicit=1 console=hvc0 debug pty.legacy_count=0
xorg-server 2:21.1.12-1ubuntu1 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support)
Current version of pixman: 0.42.2
        Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
        to make sure that you have the latest version.
Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
        (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
        (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
(==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.1.log", Time: Wed Aug  7 10:26:30 2024
(==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
xf86EnableIO: failed to enable I/O ports 0000-03ff (Function not implemented)
xf86EnableIO: failed to enable I/O ports 0000-03ff (Function not implemented)
(EE)
Fatal server error:
(EE) no screens found(EE)
(EE)
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support
         at http://wiki.x.org
 for help.
(EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.1.log" for additional information.
(EE)
(EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
xinit: giving up
xinit: unable to connect to X server: Connection refused
xinit: server error

What can I do to solve this, or is there any other ways to open ubuntu desktop from terminal?

Please edit the question and add the version of Ubuntu you are using.
